# How do you select multiple rows from a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a php script that is supposed to get multiple rows from a table and then wrap each row as an array into another array.

```
$comQy = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user = '$user' ORDER BY DESC;";
$comSt = $db->prepare($revQy);
$comRes = $comSt->execute();
$coms = $comSt->fetchAll();
```

Later in the page, I try to echo one of the elements of the array and then it doesn't work but doesn't return an error.

```
<div id="comUser">
<?php echo $coms[0]['user'] ?>
</div>
```

I appreciate all help and I am sorry if I have made a fairly simple mistake in the php script.

Comment: You are missing the column in ORDER BY **column** DESC

Comment: It should also be $comSt->execute(); instead of $comRes = $revSt->execute(), and $comSt->fetchAll() instead of $revSt->fetchAll()

Comment: Also, your query is $comQy, so it should be $db->prepare($comQy) instead of $db->prepare($revQy). You have a lot of mix matched variables that you need to resolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be the problem of

- missing the field name for the `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL query
- missing the variable declaration `$revQy`
- missing the object variable declaration `$revSt`

> $comSt = $db->prepare($revQy);
>    $comRes = $revSt->execute();

Enabling error reporting is a good practice during development. Add these lines of code at the top of your script.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I changed the names so that they are correct but it still wont do anything.

Comment: @noterate Have you tried all of three possible errors stated in my answer?

Comment: I fixed the errors that you pointed out and it is still does not work. Thanks for the help

Comment: @noterate I assumed you enabled error reporting, what errors you see?

Comment: @noterate You're welcome, I recommend to keep your original coding error in your original question so that the question and answer are on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

```
$comQy = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user = :user ORDER BY 1 DESC;";
$comSt = $db->prepare($comQy);
$comRes = $comSt->execute(array( 'user' => $user ));

$comSt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$coms = $comSt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use msqli procedural method (im just a newbie too)

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user = "'.$user.'" ORDER BY fieldname DESC';
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['user'];
}
```

Comment: The original question uses PDO. Please pay attention to these sorts of details.